# Get parent view class of view instance

Tags: android, class, view, parent, instanceof

I need a method to get the information if my View is an instance of Button.

MyButton is a subclass of Button.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle s) 
{
    ...
    MyButton button = new MyButton(activity);
    getViewType(button);
}

private <V extends View> V getViewClass(V view) 
{
    Class<V> clazz = (Class<T>) view.getClass();
    if (clazz instanceof Button) {
        return Button.class; //the information I need to get
    }
}
```

The instanceof is not working here.
I can just compare clazz with Classes like you can see below. But I need the information if this view instance is a child of the class Button.

```
if (clazz == Button.class) ... //returns false
if (clazz == MyButton.class) ... //returns true
```

**EDIT:**

I got it. Solution:

```
if (Button.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

Comment: If You found the answer, please add it as answer and accept, so question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
private <V extends View> V getViewClass(V view) 
{        
    if (view instanceof Button) {
        return Button.class; //the information I need to get
    }
}
```